# Sharing Dropbox files between Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: dual-boot, dropbox

Dropbox stopped supporting for dropbox folder on NTFS partitions in Linux. Until recently I could workaround the issue by keeping the folder on an NTFS partition and using a symbolic link to the folder on an ext4 partition.

This workaround stopped working in the past days, where dropbox started complaining that it cannot start because the folder is not on an ext4 partition. I would rather not duplicate my files since I have around 20 Gb of files and my SSD is not that big.

Any suggestions on how to workaround the issue?

Comment: ow big is your SSD? Dropbox works best when hosted on your computer's main internal drive, or on a physically connected external hard drive.

Comment: My internal SSD is 250GB of which there are two OSs, and other files besides my Dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

I see only one possible not very handy workaround in that case: to use Dropbox application only on Windows and to share (by mounting NTFS partition) the Dropbox folder with Ubuntu.

*Pros*: There will be only one folder without duplication.

*Cons*: Under Ubuntu it will be possible to read and to write to Dropbox folder. But for saving changed files in Dropbox cloud, Windows with Dropbox application must be started to perform needed update.

The similar question on Dropbox forum: [Write to a Dropbox folder on NTFS from Linux](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-files-folders/Write-to-a-Dropbox-folder-on-NTFS-from-linux/td-p/214848)